# Unable to minify css in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-optimization

I am trying to minify a css file using System.Web.Optimizations and it won't work

```
var fontAwsomeBundle = new Bundle("~/bundles/css/font-awsome", new CssMinify())
      .Include("~/content/packages/font-awesome/css/font-awesome-{version}.css", new CssRewriteUrlTransform());
```

- I have run site with optimizations enabled and debug=false
- There is no pre-minified file in the same location
- .net 4.5, IIS Express
- System.Web.Optimizations 1.1.0.0, WebGrease 1.6.5135.21930. I tried updating WebGrease to latest, but that didn't work
- I am not getting any minification errors in the bundle file, just unminified version of file

Tried this version as well. `fontAwsomeBundle.Transforms.Add(new CssMinify());`

Comment: found the culprit. Some one else is clearing all the bundle transformations in a different place.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the StyleBundle for .css and ScriptBundle for .js.

```
var fontAwsomeBundle = new StyleBundle("~/bundles/css/font-awsome", new CssMinify())
      .Include("~/content/packages/font-awesome/css/font-awesome-{version}.css", new CssRewriteUrlTransform());
```

Comment: StyleBundle does not accept CssMinify as a parameter

Comment: Correct- Style Bundle automatically adds the Css Minify.